# Not sure this elif statment failed

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am running Python 2.7.6 and when I execute the following if statement works. But if I add the commented out elif line I get a syntax error. any ideas

```
if output == 0:

  print(Num,"is Even")

# elif output = 0:

# print(Num,"is Odd" )

else:
print (Num,"is Odd")
```

Comment: Use `==` to test equality, not `=` (assignment).

Answer (score 1):

You want output==0 in the elif, which is comparison as opposed to output=0 (which is assignment)

Comment: I wanted a way to find an even or odd number. if output was not equal to 0 then x If output was equal to 0 then y. But output = 0 failed I am not sure why.

Comment: output=0 assigns output to become 0. output==0 is checking if output is 0, notice the double equal.

Comment: So a better way would be use a > to test if the output was 0 ?

Comment: No you would use a double equal sign to test if the output is 0. A single equal sign assigns the variable to be 0.